# Terminal started behaving badly when Zshell theme is present

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

Originally from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102134#).

## Versions:

- VSCode Version: 1.46.1
- OS Version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.20161

## Steps to Reproduce:

1. Install [debian-dev-boilerplate](https://github.com/DanielAtKrypton/debian-dev-boilerplate) inside WSL.
2. Setup powerlevel 10k.
3. Clone a git repo and enter its folder.

   git clone git@github.com:DanielAtKrypton/debian-dev-boilerplate.git

   cd debian-dev-boilerplate

You should now see something like:

[image: Imgur]

4. Open vscode from zshell. By typing at the zshell prompt:

   code .

At this point the bug is revealed when the terminal is opened for the first time inside vscode. At first glance, the terminal renders correctly the powerlevel10k theme. After half a second, the theme is deactivated as can be seen in the next picture.

[image: Imgur]

## Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?:

Yes. The first time vscode is launched, it installs a vanilla (with no extensions) vscode-server to the linux distro. And still the bug happens.

It is interesting to note that in prior vscode versions this functionality was working alright. For any reason I don't know this issue started to happen in the last couple weeks.

## Additional Info:

Here is the log file when running the commands:

```
code . --log trace
```

[exthost.log](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/files/4904425/exthost.log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely Powerlevel10k has been installed and/or loaded from `~/.zshrc` incorrectly. The screenshot of VS Code shows robbyrussell theme, so I surmise that you are using Oh My Zsh. To install Powerlevel10k on top of Oh My Zsh you need to follow [these instructions](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#oh-my-zsh):

1. Run: `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k`
2. Set `ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"` in `~/.zshrc`.

Try running `grep -E 'ZSH_THEME|/powerlevel10k' ~/.zshrc`. The output must be exactly like below.

```
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
```

If it's not, you need to fix `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I suggest you to follow instructions here github.com/DanielAtKrypton/debian-dev-boilerplate. And you will be able to check how Antigen loads powerlevel10k.

Comment: @DanielKaminskideSouza Indeed, that script creates incorrect Zsh configuration. To fix it, you need to delete `.zprofile` and move its content to `.zshrc`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It fixes perfectly.